# Laravel memory exception 'Database/Connection.php:301'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I got a strange bug going down here, sometimes select queries dies from a memory exception. The big problem here is that I've never been able to see the error by myself. I know its existence from users and the `laravel.log` file that contains things like :

```
[2015-03-05 11:46:07] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 196605 bytes)' in [...]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:301
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

My questions are :

- How to debug the issue (find oud what is the query that blows everything up)
- Or if there's a known workaround for this, what is it ?

I already tried to `DB::disableQueryLog();` within my `start/artisan.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message said, the error was about a certain database query. But I also asked **how** I could traceback the faulty query. I used an error tracking service called [Rollbar](https://rollbar.com) to find out which API call died. Pretty sure it isn't the *best* way to figure this out but it worked...

Answer (score 1):

**Main issue is:**

The PHP process is running out of memory, aka hitting the `memory_limit` set in your **php.ini**. The cause may be various, i.e infinite loops, large select statements; so to say: anything that requires PHP to store information in memory during processing.

**My specific Issue & Solution:**

I had this issue due to long running php processes, i.e Queue workers.

Solved it by setting up a cron job that does a `php artisan queue:restart` every 20 mins.